# Data Explorer should run the query with the Ctrl/Cmd+Enter keyboard shortcut

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts

Many other query editors use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to execute the current query, and it would be *great* if the Data Explorer could do the same.

It would save the world so much time if we all didn't have to:

1. Move our hand over to the mouse
2. drag the cursor over to the button
3. Click each time we wanted to run the query

And then, if we make a mistake, we have to reverse the process to go back to editing!

Please, help save the world and shrink the feedback loop.

Comment: If you don't have carpal tunnel, it should not be so hard to move your hand and mouse to the button. Other than that, your implementation should not be too hard to implement with some javascript magic.

Comment: +1 just for adding those symbols to the "Command" and "Enter" keys.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - [Unicode](http://tech.karbassi.com/2009/05/27/command-option-shift-symbols-in-unicode/) FTW.

Comment: jQuery-cadabra-hey-presto!

Comment: The 1-foot move from kbd to mouse + the delicate, focused movement needed to get the cursor positioned correctly takes _far_ longer and _way more effort_ than just ctrl+enter. I can hit ctrl+enter with just a quick wrist rotation and a pinkey extension for each hand, which is _way_ faster. And I can go right back to editing just as quickly, which beats out a mouse _any_ day.

Comment: @cdeszaq I find it as ***good exercise ^_^***

Answer (score 6):

Makes sense, given that you can't tab out of the field. I [added code](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=5e03dd7ef058a57f906935709809a3bdbc6cefb2) for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> case.

CodeMirror supports key binding in a fairly direct and easy way, so I don't know enough about the implementation to tell whether this will also cover the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> case (and I don't own a Mac to test). In the event that it doesn't, any inclined Mac users out there should feel free to submit a patch.

Comment: nice now if I would only stop pressing `F5`...

Comment: F5 will also now run the query.